# How to prevent "None of [MultiIndex...] are in the [columns]" in Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In the example code below, I am adding a NumPy array to a Pandas DataFrame. To avoid a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, I rewrote the code, but now I am getting a `KeyError` instead:

> "None of [MultiIndex([('new', 0),\n            ('new', 1),\n            ('new', 2)],\n           )] are in the [columns]"

This is not wrong, as the given columns *are not* in the columns. But why do they need to be?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df_ = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=[["old"], [0]])
df = df_[df_.old[0] < 4]

arr = np.random.randn(4, 3)
indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["new"], range(arr.shape[-1])])

# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
# Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
# df[indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)

# OK - I did that! This works after the previous line, but not without it:
df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)
```

Comment: `df = df_[df_.old[0] < 4]` creates a copy. From this point on, whenever you modify `df`, you are modifying a sliced copy of `df_`. Should `df = df_[df_.old[0] < 4].copy()` or change only `df_` directly

Comment: To avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`, `del df_` is also very effective.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=[["old"], [0]])
df = df_[df_.old[0] < 4]
```

where `df` is a slice of `df_`. Copy it:

```
df_ = pd.DataFrame(range(10), columns=[["old"], [0]])
df = df_[df_.old[0] < 4].copy()
```

---

**Update**: per your comment,

```
df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)
```

doesn't work because they have different columns. The left hand side has MultiIndex  columns `indices` while the right hand side has RangeIndex columns `0,1,2`. Should it work if it were:

```
df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=indices)
```

or

```
df.loc[:, indices] = arr
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)` still does not work :(

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the difference between `MultiIndex` and `RangeIndex`!

Comment: I think I accepted too early: neither `df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns=indices)` nor `df.loc[:, indices] = arr` work for me.

Comment: Also, note that `df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)` *does* work after `df[indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)` has been made, so I don't think the kind of indexing matters here.

Comment: @bers my update was based on the fact that `df[indices] = pd.DataFrame(...)` has been made. If the columns are already there, you need column alignment to update the data. To attach new data, e.g. without `df[indices] = ...` you can try `concat` or `join`.

Comment: If `df[indices] = pd.DataFrame(...)` has been made, then I don't need an alternative to `df.loc[:, indices] = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index)`, because it  works.

Comment: Then make a copy: `df = df_[df_.old[0] < 4].copy()`, and use `df[indices] = ...`

Comment: I updated the title of my question to focus on the `MultiIndex` issue - it is explained by a `SettingWithCopyWarning` here, but I am looking for a general solution for the former issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question about the "None of MultiIndex... are in the [columns]" error.

I made a simple test (to remove the `SettingWithCopyWarning` factor) with single-index columns, and it worked fine to use `df.loc` with non-existent column labels. But if you do the exact same commands with a list of multi-index column labels, it fails. It seems like a pandas bug to me. (pandas v1.3.3, python v3.9.5)

```
# single index

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({ 'old0':[0,1,2,3] })

   old0
0     0
1     1
2     2
3     3

>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame({ 'new0':[10]*4, 'new1':[11]*4, 'new2':[12]*4 })

   new0  new1  new2
0    10    11    12
1    10    11    12
2    10    11    12
3    10    11    12

>>> df.loc[:, ['new0', 'new1', 'new2'] ] = new_df

   old0  new0  new1  new2
0     0    10    11    12
1     1    10    11    12
2     2    10    11    12
3     3    10    11    12

# multi-index

>>> mdf = pd.DataFrame({ ('old',0):[0,1,2,3] })

  old
    0
0   0
1   1
2   2
3   3

>>> new_mdf = pd.DataFrame({ ('new',0):[10]*4, ('new',1):[11]*4, ('new',2):[12]*4 })

  new        
    0   1   2
0  10  11  12
1  10  11  12
2  10  11  12
3  10  11  12

>>> mdf.loc[:, [('new',0), ('new',1), ('new',2)] ] = new_mdf

KeyError: "None of [MultiIndex([('new', 0),\n            ('new', 1),\n            ('new', 2)],\n           )] are in the [columns]"
```